# Difference between local and production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload, bundling-and-minification, blueimp, backload

I am using NuGet package Backload (in MVC5 project).
All works properly in local IIS (Visual Studio 2015).
But in production server I have error:

```
/loading.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I watched Resurces tab in Chrome DevTools and what i see:

Production:

```
http://xxxxx.xx/backload/blueimp/bootstrap/img/loading.gif
```

Local:

```
http://localhost:2643/Backload/Client/blueimp/fileupload/img/loading.gif
```

I find a file (**jquery.fileupload-ui.css**) containing:

```
background: url("../img/loading.gif")
```

Yes, i can override style, but what works not correctly?

[image: Local]
[image: Production]

**UPDATE**
after set

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true" />
```

All works, without error 404

Why it can't work on release?

Minification?

Comment: try to check physically if file exists in prod server, if you have access?

Comment: Yes, exists in the same folder

Comment: So... the image exist in production server in this path `/blueimp/bootstrap/img/` or in this path: `/blueimp/fileupload/img/`?

Comment: No, Image is in folder `/Backload/Client/blueimp/fileupload/img/`

Comment: jquery.fileupload-ui.css in `/Backload/Client/blueimp/fileupload/css/`

Comment: "backload/blueimp/bootstrap" is part of the name of the bundle you use. You can find it in ~/Backload/Bundles/BackloadBundles.cs. This bundle name will be resolved to the real path at runtime. But this should affect all client files, not only the loading image.

Comment: @helgans, I agree with you. I have BackloadBundles.cs, all works except not right path of loading.gif as if BackloadBundles not work. The second question is why everything works locally.

Comment: Is "jquery.fileupload-ui.css" really loaded from this path "~/Backload/Client/blueimp/fileupload/css/"? Because, if the css is loaded from the correct path the bundle system works. The loading image is requested from the browser (client side) and bundling (server side) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @helgans Yes, loaded from this path.

Comment: Now, on production server i set <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="**true**" /> and all works

Comment: A little bit strange. Maybe you used an older version before and this thing was kind of a remains. Can you tell me what backload version you use, because I want to check if this can be a problem in our products.

Comment: @helgans Today I updated the version up 2.1.0.0

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this in our products too.

Comment: something works not so in minification process, because debug="true" turn off minification

Comment: That's true. Instead of using the bundle feature you can manually reference the files. Here are the files backload references for the individual bundles: https://github.com/blackcity/backload/wiki/Script-and-style-bundles#basic-plus-ui-theme